# Using negative margin of 4px to remove distance between inline-block divs

Tags: css

I have seen a lot of css which uses `margin-right: -4px` to get rid of the space between inline-divs. Why is -4 being used? And is it going to work everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-4 is used when the width of a space is 4 pixels. It's completely arbitrary, completely dependent on the font metrics (family, size, etc), and therefore by definition not going to work everywhere.

It's this utterly arbitrary value that makes this one of those workarounds that *really* highlights the fatal flaw of using inline-blocks for (horizontal) block layout in the first place.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. So I guess -4 is more of a hack than a solution. What should be used for horizontal layouts then? Flex maybe?

Answer (score 1):

This is how inline-block works. if you want your divs stay in the block but be inline you can use inline-block, there are more tricks to fix this, one of them is `margin-left: -4px`, you can find more from the link here:

https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

I suggest to use `CSS Grid` to create blocks for layout. Here is a website to find some example for CSS Grid:

https://gridbyexample.com/examples/